# How to add get/set accessors?

Tags: c#, random, get, set

Create a C# console application that uses overloaded methods to calculate the average of 2, 3 or 4 integers.  First create a class Average.  Write a method play in this class to do the following:

(1) Generate a random integer to decide whether to calculate the average of 2, 3 or 4 integers.
(2) Generate 2, 3 or 4 random integers. These random integers must be in the range 1 to 1000.
(3) Call one of three versions of the method CalcAverage to calculate the average of the random integers.
(4) Display the random integers and their average in the console window.

The Average class should have three versions of the method CalcAverage, taking two, three and four integers as arguments, respectively. Create a AverageTest class.  In the Main method, create an instance of Average and then call its Play method.

and what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace lab09_ex03
{
    public class Average
    {
        public int play();
        {
            Random randomNumbers = new Random();
            int numIntegers = randomNumbers.Next(2, 5);
            Console.WriteLine("For this round the program will display the average of\n {0} randomly generated integers", numIntegers);
            if (numIntegers == 2)
                {
                    int integer01 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                    int integer02 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                    return integer01, integer02;
                }
                if (numIntegers == 3)
                    {
                        int integer01 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                        int integer02 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                        int integer03 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                        return integer01, integer02, integer03;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        int integer01 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                        int integer02 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                        int integer03 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                        int integer04 = randomNumbers.Next(1, 1001);
                        return integer01, integer02, integer03, integer04;
                    }
        }
        public int CalcAverage(int integer01, int integer02)
        {
            int average01 = (integer01 + integer02)/2;
            Console.WriteLine("The average of {0} and {1} is {2}", integer01, integer02, average01);
        }
        public int CalcAverage(int integer01, int integer02, int integer03)
        {
            int average02 = (integer01 + integer02 + integer03)/3;
            Console.WriteLine("The average of {0} and {1} and {2} is {3}", integer01, integer02, integer03, average02);
        }
        public int CalcAverage(int integer01, int integer02, int integer03, int integer04)
        {
            int average03 = (integer01 + integer02 + integer03 + integer04)/4;
            Console.WriteLine("The average of {0} and {1} and {2} and {3} is {4}", integer01, integer02, integer03, integer04, average03);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Play p = new Play();
            int integer01;
            int integer02;
            int integer03;
            int integer04;
            Console.WriteLine(p.Play());
            Console.WriteLine(p.CalcAverage(integer01, integer02));
            Console.WriteLine(p.CalcAverage(integer01, integer02, integer03));
            Console.WriteLine(p.CalcAverage(integer01, integer02, integer03, integer04));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't actually ask us a question.  SO probably won't just do your homework for you.  Are you stuck on something specific?

Comment: Please post sample related to your question. Currently post contains some random homework assignment of questionable quality instead of showing some presumed problem with get/set accessors.

Comment: Visual studio error - A get or set accessor expected @ Random randomNumbers = new Random();

Answer (score 0):

First off, `play` is a method, so it needs to be `public int Play()`. (Unless this is what you are trying to access using get/set? If that's the case, it isn't good convention at all.) 
And I'm not sure I understand the question you are asking here. If you want something to have get and set methods, it goes something like this:

```
private int myPrivateValue = 0;
public int myPublicValue
{
    get
    {
        return myPrivateValue;
    }
    set
    {
        myPrivateValue = value;
    }
}
```

You can read up on it from the official Microsoft reference site here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Edit: The purpose of something like get/set is when you have multiple classes to validate input, make a log of it being changed, etc... You have your public value, which is like a way for other classes to have limited access to your private fields.

Comment: True, that does need to be fixed. Thanks.